# How to use LINQ syntax to select out of my XDocument all those XElements that have a certain attribute value?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I need to create a new XDocument based on another XDocument, and so want to loop through all the XElements of the original XDocument, adding only those XElements which pass a certain criteria to the new XDocument.

The problem is that my variable "duplicates" is always null, but it should always a least contain the one element which is current at that moment.

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument();
XElement rootElement = new XElement("users");
var allElements = originalDoc.Element("users").Elements().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "user");
foreach (var xUser in allElements)
{
    var duplicates = originalDoc.Element("users").Elements().Where(e => e.Attribute("Login").Value == "Demo1");
    rootElement.Add(xUser);
}
doc.Add(rootElement);
return doc;
```

Where originalDoc is an XDocument, what is the LINQ syntax to select out of my XDocument at that point all those XElements that have a certain attribute value?

## Addendum:

Here's what the XML looks like, no namespaces or any extras, just the root element and one level of sub-elements:

```
<users>
  <user ProjectName="TheCompany1" ProjectSlug="testName" Login="Demo1" Name="Test user" ActivationState="FullyActivated" Country="" Created="2011-03-04T20:32:04.367" IsCustomUser="false" DeleteFilesOnLogout="false" Email="validation@company.com" IsDefaultLoginUser="true" IsDefaultTestUser="false" IsLockedOut="false" MaxFileSize="300000" PostFileEnabled="true" RestServiceEnabled="false" Salutation=""Groups="Everyone" />
  <user ProjectName="TheCompany2" ProjectSlug="testName" Login="Demo2" Name="Test user" ActivationState="FullyActivated" Country="" Created="2011-03-04T20:32:04.367" IsCustomUser="false" DeleteFilesOnLogout="false" Email="validation@company.com" IsDefaultLoginUser="true" IsDefaultTestUser="false" IsLockedOut="false" MaxFileSize="300000" PostFileEnabled="true" RestServiceEnabled="false" Salutation=""Groups="Everyone" />
  <user ProjectName="TheCompany3" ProjectSlug="testName" Login="Demo3" Name="Test user" ActivationState="FullyActivated" Country="" Created="2011-03-04T20:32:04.367" IsCustomUser="false" DeleteFilesOnLogout="false" Email="validation@company.com" IsDefaultLoginUser="true" IsDefaultTestUser="false" IsLockedOut="false" MaxFileSize="300000" PostFileEnabled="true" RestServiceEnabled="false" Salutation=""Groups="Everyone" />
</users>
```

Comment: @bommelding I posted the XML above, very straight-forward: one-level of elements and no namespaces, etc.

Comment: I've tried many combinations including `originalDoc.Element("users").Elements().Where(e => e.Attribute("Login").Value == xUser.Attribute("Login").Value)` which I think is what you meant here, but the result is always null, regardless. `allElements` is not an `XDocument`, of course, but an `IEnumerable<XElement> collection, so I need to access it differently and am trying to figure out how.

Comment: The variable `duplicates` is always null, where the variable `allElements` has the content from the XML file, i.e. `e.Name.LocalName == "user"` works to get the name of the elements, but not `e.Attribute("Login") == xUser.Login` to get the content of the element's attributes.

Comment: Well, `e.Attribute("Login")` should be `e.Attribute("Login").Value`, `xUser.Login` is invalid C#. And you should go back to `allElements.Where()`

Comment: Ok, sorry, that was an oversight from reducing the code to an example. I changed the code now to show that it doesn't work with this: `var duplicates = originalDoc.Element("users").Elements().Where(e => e.Attribute("Login").Value == "Demo1");`. It's as if `e.Attribute("Login").Value` is not the correct syntax and so finds nothing.

Comment: I've decided to solve this a different way and am running into a similar problem. I suspect it was simply not showing me the values while debugging even though the values where there, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50700485/why-do-the-values-of-my-tuple-collection-not-show-up-in-watch

Answer (score 0):

Two quick fixes are required!

First of all the XML fragment is not well-formed. Look for `« Salutation=""Groups=»` which should be `« Salutation="" Groups=»`.

Secondly just change your query a bit,

```
var duplicates = originalDoc.Element("users").Elements().Where(e => e.Attribute("Login").Value=="Demo1");
```

to this

```
var duplicates = originalDoc.Root.Elements().Where(e => e.Attribute("Login").Value=="Demo1");
                           ^^^^^^^
```

And your are all done...Or you may use **[Descendants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-find-descendants-with-a-specific-element-name)** otherwise.

Hope this helps!