# Why do the values of my tuple collection not show up in watch?

Tags: c#, tuples

Why is it that when I run this console app:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var items = new List<(string login, string email)>();
    items.Add(("james", "lsdkjsdkj@skdfjd.dfkd"));
    items.Add(("james2", "lsdkjsdkj@df333.dfkd"));
    items.Add(("james", "lsdkjsdkj@skdfjd.dfkd"));
    items.Add(("james2", "lsdkjsdkj@df333.dfkd"));

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.email);
    }

    var duplicates = items.Where(e => e.login == "james");
    Console.WriteLine(duplicates.Count());

    foreach (var duplicate in duplicates)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Found: {duplicate.login}, {duplicate.email}");
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

it correctly shows me the contents of the variable `duplicates`:

[image]

but when I debug, it doesn't show me the contents of `duplicates`:

[image]

Comment: It shows inside `Results View`.

Comment: If you had added ToList() after the Where clause, it should have shown up at that point. duplicates is just an Enumerable and needs to be enumerated. LINQ is lazy unless you force the enumeration with something like ToList or ToArray. And SeM's answer is correct, coming at it from a more direct perspective.

Comment: The odd thing here is that `duplicates` *shouldn't **have** `.Current`. `IEnumerable` has `GetEnumerator` and `GetEnumerator` returns an `IEnumerator` that does. The odd thing is that `duplicates`, before being enumerated, have the `.Current` property.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen That's not even only `Tuple`, I've tested  with `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();`, same result, `Current` property exists when debugging. Edit: Well, it shows `Current` every time, even in `(new string[] { "james", "james2", "james", "james2" }).Where(s => s == "james");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Current`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.current(v=vs.110).aspx) property is just an element in the collection at the current position of the enumerator.

From MSDN:

> Current is undefined under any of the following conditions:
>
> - The enumerator is positioned before the first element in the    collection, immediately after the enumerator is created. [MoveNext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.movenext(v=vs.110).aspx) must be called to advance the enumerator to the first element of the collection before reading the value of Current.
> - The last call to MoveNext returned false, which indicates the end of the collection.
> - The enumerator is invalidated due to changes made in the collection, such as adding, modifying, or deleting elements.

So if you call `duplicates.GetEnumerator().MoveNext();` and you will see that your `Current` now have data in it.

If you want see your `duplicates` content while debugging, use `Results View`.

Comment: It's odd that the *Enumerable* have the Current property, and not the *Enumerator*, unless for such iterables they've faked it and combined, but that seems odd as well.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen It's very odd, there is something to do with `Tuples` I guess.